# Making a kick command

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am making a "ban command" there is a obvious issue here
just really dumb so i'll need help please.

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
@client.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, user, *, reason):
    try:
        await user.ban(delete_messages_days=4)
    except:
        print('USER BAN ATTEMPT FAILED.')
        ctx.send("I can't ban {}".format(user))
```

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=has_permissions#discord.ext.commands.has_permissions

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`@commands.has_permissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?#discord.ext.commands.has_permissions) decorator on the command with the permissions `kick_members` and `ban_members`:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True, ban_members=True)
async def command(ctx):
    pass
```